# white space at end of HTML email

Tags: html, email, inline, newsletter

Getting a ton of white space at the end of my HTML email.

obviously, outlook is the worst? Any help? Attached is the code & a screen shot.

http://danielmdesigns.com/test/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-09%20at%205.59.55%20PM.png

http://codepen.io/dwmaldonado/full/Byjbao

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> <title>eCommission - Get your Golden Ticket Today!</title> <style type="text/css"></style> <style type="text/css"> /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
#outlook a { padding:0; }  .ReadMsgBody { width:100%; } .ExternalClass { width:100%; } .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; } body, table, td, a {
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; } table, td { mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; } img {
-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */ body { height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; } img { border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none; } table { border-collapse:collapse !important; }

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */ .apple-link a { color:#999999 !important; text-decoration: none !important; } </style> </head>

    <body>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" border-collapse="collapse" width="100%" height="1000" bgcolor="#ededed">
    <tr style="page-break-before: always">
        <td>

        <!-- Header Logo & Image -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="200">
        <a href="#"><img border="0" src="https://echo3.bluehornet.com/cimages/056f203db71e325409aa569351f79757/eCommission_GoldenTicketHeader.png" alt="eCommission - This Golden Ticket gets you your commissions before closing" style="display:block;"></a>
        </td>
        </tr>

            <!-- Content -->
            <tr>
            <td width="600" style="margin:100px; margin-left:100px; margin-right:100px; padding:10px; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; line-height:22px;">
            <p style="margin:30px 30px;">There is nothing better than spending the holidays knowing your business has access to cash at any time. A commission advance from <b>eCommission</b> lets you control when you get paid, by advancing your commissions from pending sales and active listings whenever you want them.</p>  

<p style="margin:30px 30px;">Using <b>eCommission</b> is fast, easy, and confidential:
     <br>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;• Apply on-line in minutes <br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;• Request up to $15,000 <br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;• Receive and sign your documents electronically <br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;• Have your funds wired in 1 business day <br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;• No Credit Check <br> </p>

<p style="margin:30px 30px;"> <b><span style="color:#ff8d06;">*Special Holiday Offer*</span></b> New customers get <b><span style="color:#ff8d06;">50%</span></b> off the advance fee, an average savings of $350!* Code will automatically apply on your first transaction.</p>

<p style="margin:30px 30px;"> Get started today at eCommission.com or call toll free at 877-882-4368.</p>

            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Button -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
            <td width="200"></td>
            <td align="center" width="200" height="50" bgcolor="#ff8d06" font-color="#ffffff" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;"><a href="#" style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; line-height:50px; display:inline-block; width:100%;"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Get Started</span></a></td>
            <td width="200"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Disclaimer Information -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding:20px 10px 20px 10px; font-family:arial; font-size:9px; line-height:12px; color:#808080;"><i>*Savings of $350 based on a commission advance of $4,000 closing within 40 days. Certain underwriting restrictions apply. Hurry, offer expires December 31, 2014. Copyright 2014 eCommission Financial Services, Inc. 11612 Bee Caves Rd. Bldg. 2, Suite 200, Austin, Texas 78738</i></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Footer Logos -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
            <td width="2%"></td>
            <td width="25%"><img border="0" src="https://echo3.bluehornet.com/cimages/056f203db71e325409aa569351f79757/logo_bbb.gif" alt="BBB A+ Acredited Business" style="display:block;"></td>
            <td width="25%"><img border="0" src="https://echo3.bluehornet.com/cimages/056f203db71e325409aa569351f79757/logo_verify.png" alt="Verified & Secured, Verify Security" style="display:block;"></td>
            <td width="48%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body> </html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Emails don't get full HTML bodies. Make the email work as though it was just inside of a DIV.

Comment: Thanks for the help David! Could you give me an example of what you mean? I just want to be clear that I understand you correctly.

Comment: As in, you have `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>`, and `<body>`. All of those will already be on the webpage the person is using to view the email, so you having them there is bound to mess something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found that the issue was actually because of the email test service i am using. they provide additional white space within their screen shots to make sure the full length of the email is captured. This is a limitation of the email capturing process, and not an issue with my email =)